# Install Qt SDK on Mac OS X Snow Leopard 32 bit

Tags: macos, qt, qt4, installation, 32-bit

I want to install Qt on Mac OS X Snow Leopard 32-bit but on the qt-project website only the version for 64 bit is available.

I tried to install the libraries and the Qt Creator IDE separately but it doesn't work, I get the error "`:-1: error: /Developer/Tools/Qt/moc: Bad CPU type in executable`".

I also tried to compile the sources which i got from [here](http://download.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1.tar.gz) but all i got were errors:

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `../../WebCore/debug/libwebcored.a', needed by `../../../../../../lib/QtWebKit.framework/QtWebKit_debug'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [debug-install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-WebKit-qt-QtWebKit-pro-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
make: *** [sub-webkit-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
```

Everywhere I search on the web i get broken links from the old Nokia Qt website or people telling that Qt is not available for 32bit on Mac.
I'd like to install Qt on his Mac even if it's an older version.

Does anyone know a link to the source code that works or a .dmg file for the entire Qt SDK bundle that works for Snow Leopard 32-bit?

I also installed XCode 3.2.6.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth trying to use macports or other pacjakimg systems

Comment: Can you please give me some details? Haven't used macports before.
Should I install something?

Comment: Start at http://www.macports.org/install.php

Comment: I successfully installed mac ports. How will this help me?

Comment: Look for and install the ports you want - in this case I would assume qt4-mac `port info <portname>` tells you what it is. `sudo port install <portname>` does the install. However please read some of the macports site documentation to understand what t does and how it works

Comment: I installed qt from macports and it installed Assistant, Designer, Linguist and the others but no Creator. I installed Creator separately but how can i configure it use the libraries? Where are them installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might either have to build from source or get an older version of Qt built for 32bit. I believe 4.6.x had support for 32bit systems. Take a look at the official docs on developing for Mac with Qt: http://doc.qt.digia.com/latest/developing-on-mac.html

Comment: The latest Qt version supports 32-bit OS X 10.6 just fine. I'm using it myself for both 32-bit Intel as well as PPC.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I haven't tried targetting for 32-bit in a while since I only try to support OS X 10.6 or higher with deployment.